# trying to make navigation bar for tablet site

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jqtouch, tablet

I'm designing a navigation bar for a tablet website. The navigation bar holds elements displayed horizontally, and I want to be able to display new elements with a swipe (kind of like a cover flow) without the window moving. This is the code I'm using now (jQuery Mobile):

```
//Tablet Features
        $('#navHolder').bind('swipe', 
            function(e) {
              $('#navHolder').animate({left:thisLeft - 100});
            }
        );
```

I dont think I can trigger a `swipe` without first disabling scroll, but I'm open to all suggestions. Please help.

Comment: Can you post your navigation bar html and javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parent container of the element you are scrolling to `overflow : hidden` so no scroll-bars appear. Then `swipe` events should work fine since you won't be able to use native scrolling to scroll the content.

HTML --

```
    <div id="navHolder-container">
        <div id="navHolder">
            <p>content in here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS --

```
#navHolder {
    position : absolute;
    width    : 1000px;
}
#navHolder-container {
    position : relative;
    overflow : hidden;
    height   : 100px;
    width    : 100%;
}
```

JS --

```
$(function () {
    var convert = {
            swipeleft  : '-=100',
            swiperight : '+=100'
        };
    $('#navHolder-container').bind('swipeleft swiperight', function(e) {
        $('#navHolder').animate({ left: convert[e.type]});
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B8PQn/1/

Comment: @Jasper--I tried this, and even if overflow is set to hidden, overflow elements appear in a new row **underneath** the other elements. This would be ideal for a vertical navbar but it does not work for a horizontal one. Any other ideas?

Comment: The inner element (the child of the container element) has to have a set width so it doesn't wrap. Just start by giving it a really big width like `2000px`.

Comment: Also make sure to set the `position : relative` or `position : absolute` (even better) on the element you want to animate, this is a requirement in CSS. Here is a working demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/B8PQn/1/

Comment: @Jasper--why have you chosen to use an anonymous function? also, what is `convert[e.type]` supposed to do?

Comment: `$(function () {});` is a `document.ready` event handler, the code within will only run once the DOM is ready. `event.type` returns the type of event that triggered the event handler to run. `convert` is a variable that takes in a value and outputs another. It takes in the event type (`swipeleft`/`swiperight`) and returns the correct offset for the animation. For example, if the user `swiperight`s, the `swiperight` string is passed into the `convert` variable and the output is `+=100` so the element animates to the right. The same goes for `swileleft` but it animates the element to the left.

Comment: @Jasper--my events are being triggered twice.... do you have any ideas on why this is happening?